# Declaring a class inline of ASPX-age

Tags: c#, asp.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to set up a receive-page to collect data, which is formatted as a JSON-string, being sent to us from an external service and which we have to add to our database.

For the sake of simplicity, I would like to keep all the code in one page which is linked to this external service.

I can receive the JSON-string, but I can't seem to deserialize it because it won't accept my class.

My code is shown below.
For debugging reasons I'm also exporting the data to an external log.
If some date would not be added, I can try to see the log if there is anything special in that message which is causing issues.

If I remove my class from the code the page will load correctly.
If I put the class in it, it will throw an error (which I can't see because I'm using an online webserver).

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ import namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>


<%

public class MessageClass
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    public string url;
    public string user_name;
    public int timestamp;
}

// GET THE CONTENT THAT WAS POSTED
//StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
//string requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();
string requestFromPost = "{type:'image',url:'https://someservice.com/picture.jpg',user_name:'user',timestamp:1511772572733}";

Response.Write(requestFromPost);

// BACKUP THE MESSAGE IN A LOG
StreamWriter sw;
try
{
  sw = File.AppendText(Server.MapPath(".\\") + "test.log");
  sw.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") +"] " + requestFromPost);
  sw.Flush();
  sw.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // IGNORE
}




StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
//var response = ser.Deserialize<MessageClass>(requestFromPost);

//Response.Write(response.url);


// DATABASE STUFF GOES BELOW

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to changes the data type for timestamp to long since it is not a valid integer

Comment: true Haitham, but I needed to change it to DateTime anyway afterwards but I was aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for my question, eventhough I don't think it's the best solution.

I've put the class inside -tags.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ import namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Web" %>
<%@ import namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>

<script runat="server">

    public class MessageClass
    {
        public string type;
        public string text;
        public string url;
        public string user_name;
        public long timestamp;
    }

</script>


<%



// GET THE CONTENT THAT WAS POSTED
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
string requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();



// DESERIALIZE THE CONTENT
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var response = ser.Deserialize<MessageClass>(requestFromPost);
```

However if someone has a better suggestion to keep it in the same code block, I'm all ears!